# Assign weights to the edges

Tags: r, igraph

I made a graph from [this text file](https://ufile.io/lc91y)
I try to assign weights to the edges by jaccard similarity

```
 dat<-read.delim(file.choose(),header = F)
> g<-graph_from_data_frame(dat,directed = F)
> g<-simplify(g)
> sim<-similarity.jaccard(g)
> el<-get.edgelist(g)
> E(g)$weight <- sim[el]
```

But sends these errore:

```
*Warning message:
In length(eattrs[[name]]) <- ec : length of NULL cannot be changed*
```

or

```
*Error in sim[el] : subscript out of bounds*
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to get.edgelist is returning the vertex ids as characters, but you want to use them as a numeric matrix to index your jaccard scores

```
el<-get.edgelist(g)
el<-apply(el, 2, as.numeric) #convert to numeric matrix
E(g)$weight <- sim[el]
```